# Folium custom pop-up

Tags: python, folium

Running Python 3.5.2 with Folium 0.3.0.

I am trying to create custom pop-ups appear whenever I click on a specific country with data. I manage to get the pop-ups appear, but I'm lost in passing in values dynamically into them. I'm familiar with Python but new to JSON etc.

I start with having a Series object `final_dict`. Further, I have a country polygon data set `countries_reduced.json`. Following [example found here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/341), I hack the folium.GeoJson template to include highlighting when I hover the mouse over a country with data, and further to display a pop-up when I click the country. The pop-up itself displays just fine, however so far I have only managed to pass in *some* value from `final_dict` (e.g. `final_dict[0]`) for *all* the countries, as done by line

```
var html_aaa = $('<div id="html_aaa" style="width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;">"""+ "{0:.2f}%".format(final_dict[0] * 100) + """</div>')[0];
```

in the code snippet below. For example, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVYes.png), the pop-up for the U.S. reads `-0.02%` although it should read `0.18%`.

**Any ideas how to dynamically pass in the value corresponding to the clicked country into the pop-up?**

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data
array = np.array([-0.000247 , 0.00178 , -0.0183 , 0.00831 , 0.0135 , -0.00266 , 0.00461])
final_dict = pd.Series(array, index=['JPN', 'USA', 'ARG', 'DEU', 'SWE', 'FIN' , 'FRA'])

# Create map
import json
import folium
geo_json_data = json.load(open('countries_reduced.json'))
linear = folium.LinearColormap(['red','yellow','green'], vmin=-0.02, vmax=0.02)
linear.to_step(21)

m = folium.Map([0,0], tiles='Mapbox Bright', zoom_start=2)
g = folium.GeoJson(
    geo_json_data,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': linear(final_dict[feature['id']]),                    
        'color' : 'black',
        'weight' : 2,
        'dashArray' : '5, 5'
        }, 
    ).add_to(m)

 # Following example provided here: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/341,
 # I overwrite the g_Template 
from jinja2 import Template    
g._template = Template("""
            {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
               var {{this.get_name()}} = {};                
               var popup_aaa = L.popup({maxWidth: '300'});
               var html_aaa = $('<div id="html_aaa" style="width: 100.0%; height: 100.0%;">"""+ "{0:.2f}%".format(final_dict[0] * 100) + """</div>')[0];
               popup_aaa.setContent(html_aaa);                

                {{this.get_name()}}.style = function(feature) {return feature.properties.style;};

                {{this.get_name()}}.highlightStyle = function(feature) {return {
                        weight: 5,
                        color: '#666',
                        dashArray: '',
                        fillOpacity: 0.7
                        };
                    };
                {{this.get_name()}}.onEachFeature = function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                    layer.on({
                        mouseover: function(e) {
                            e.target.setStyle({{this.get_name()}}.highlightStyle(e.target.feature));
                            e.target.bindPopup(popup_aaa);},
                        mouseout: function(e) {
                            {{this.get_name()}}.geoJson.resetStyle(e.target);
                            }
                        });
                    };
                {{this.get_name()}}.geoJson = L.geoJson(
                    {% if this.embed %}{{this.style_data()}}{% else %}"{{this.data}}"{% endif %},{
                        style : {{this.get_name()}}.style,
                        onEachFeature: {{this.get_name()}}.onEachFeature
                        })
                    .addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
            {% endmacro %}
""")    

# And draw the map with additions, save
m.add_child(g)
m.add_child(linear)
m.save('map4.html')
```

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meanwhile? I'm facing the same issue and the only workaround I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595931/show-different-pop-ups-for-different-polygons-in-a-geojson-folium-python-ma), but it makes my map with roughly 1500 polygons really heavy/not loaded at all.

Comment: Thanks to he link! Unfortunately, I haven't found a proper solution. Since asking this I have bitten the bullet and started learning Javascript for browser-based visualizations. Not the fastest approach but once you get the hang of it pays off with more degrees of freedom in customizing stuff :)

Comment: Okay, good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The index that you are using in `final_dict[0]` is for Japan, and not the US.

To be sure you could change that line to `final_dict['USA']`.

Comment: This is still not dynamic, right? It would display the USA value for all countries...